# What is the correct way to determine Qibla (the direction of prayer)?

Tags: salat, qiblah

What is the correct way to determine the direction of Qibla?

If I give "San Francisco" as origin in [this site](http://www.qibla.com.br/), the direction can be East or North, based on whether I choose "Constant Compass" or "Shortest Distance" option

Where are the direction of qibla of mosques in San Francisco?

Comment: In the last sentence you mean "[..] the direction of *qibla* in [..]"?

Answer (score 4):

According to the below Fatwa from Imam Khamenei (Ayatollah Khamenei) the shortest distance should be chosen and if there is a point that different directions have the same distance then he is free to choose any direction he wishes.

---

**Reference:**

[Prayer rulings, Qiblah, Q367](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?uid=3&tid=3)